# Sum of instance variables in Array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, instance-variables

I have an array *item_list = [item1, item2, item3,]* that stores objects that have prices.
I would like to do the sum of those prices and display it as a Total.

I tried to do this:

```
print "Items:"
item_list.each do |item|
  print " #{item.name},"
  prices_arr = []
  prices_arr << item.price
  sum = prices_arr.sum
end
  puts "Total: #{sum}"
```

But I get the error, undefined local variable or method `sum'.
If I put "Total: #{sum}" in the loop it will give me each item followed by its price but not a total.
Any thoughts?

Comment: In each iteration of `each` you are creating a brand new `prices_arr`.  I suspect that's not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the variable **sum** is defined inside the loop, and that is why its scope is limited inside that

```
print "Items:"
item_list.each do |item|
  print " #{item.name},"
  prices_arr = []
  prices_arr << item.price
  sum = prices_arr.sum
end
puts "Total: #{sum}"
```

So, a better way would be :-

```
sum = 0
print "Items:"
item_list.each do |item|
  print " #{item.name},"
  sum += item.price
end
puts "Total: #{sum}"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a great opportunity to use something like inject. Starting with a sum of 0 you can do something like the following. This allows you to both printand work with the data item but also combine it with an arbitrary accumulator (in this case an integer that starts as 0).

```
print "Items:"
sum = item_list.inject(0) do |sum, item|
  print " #{item.name},"
  sum += item.price
end
puts "Total: #{sum}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's first create an example array `item_list`.

```
class List
  attr_reader :name, :price
  def initialize(name, price)
    @name, @price = name, price
  end
end

item_list = [List.new("tools", 148.16), List.new("food", 265.13),
             List.new("hair", 84.51), List.new("books", 285.01)]
  #=> [#<List:0x000000019043a8 @name="tools", @price=148.16>,
  #    #<List:0x000000019042e0 @name="food", @price=265.13>,
  #    #<List:0x00000001904268 @name="hair", @price=84.51>,
  #    #<List:0x000000019041a0 @name="books", @price=285.01>]
```

We may now print the desired values.

```
print "Items:"
puts " Total: %.2f" % item_list.sum do |item|
  print " #{item.name},"
  item.price
end
  # tools, food, hair, books, Total: 782.81
```

Comment: Additionally `List` could use `def coerce(other); [self.price,other]; end` then it can `sum` itself e.g. `puts "#{item_list.map(&:name).join(', ')} Total: %.2f" % item_list.sum`

Comment: @engineersmnky, that's very cool. I'd not used [Numeric#coerce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-coerce) before. In general I suppose the `coerce` method could perform a validity test on `other` and raise an exception if it didn't pass.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sum = item_list.map(&:price).sum
```

Comment: Just use `.sum`

Comment: Almost, I think, @SergioTulentsev was mean this: `sum = item_list.sum(&:price)` :)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko: yep. 2.4+, though.